# Bim360 api - 429 - too many requests

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We have desktop and mobile app (2 different client id) integrated with bim360 api. We have a problem with 429 error responses. Documentation: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/rate-limiting/ doesn't give us a lot of details. 
How does it work? How can we avoid it? 
What will happen if 1000 different users from apps with the same client_id at once try to get issues list? Will it be distinguish as Ddos? Are hubId, projectId, user account, ip address considered in rate-limiting algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, each API has a well-configured rate-limit per minute per client id. After reaching the limit, you will see a `retry-After` parameter appears in the response header of each of your API call. It stands for the retry time when you can call the API again, and the unit of this value is in second. You can schedule a retry task along this retry time in your code.

**Note.** The value of the `retry-After` will reset if you make another call before reaching the Retry-After duration.

Hope it help, Cheers!

Comment: But if the rate-limit is per client_id, not userId or IP - it means that we can't handle many concurrent users. And retry-after gives us nothing, because at the same time, on the different mobile someone else can reset it. Correct?